# How to support datetime comparison in a query on a server that does not support timezone tables

Tags: mysql, date, view, comparison, convert-tz

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM article 
WHERE online= 1 
AND IF(ISNULL(dateHOnline), dateHCreation, dateHOnline) <= Convert_TZ(Now(), "SYSTEM", "Europe/Paris")
```

But `Convert_TZ(Now(),"SYSTEM","Europe/Paris")` returns `null`, probably because my mysql server does not support timezone tables (putting +02:00 return a datetime).

So how can I modify that request (it's a VIEW) to implement the daylight saving feature in the comparison. I guess that just putting `+02:00` instead of `Europe/Paris` would not be enough.

PS : I do not have control over the mysql engine

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to [load timezone information into mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql tz_dir
```

Comment: That does not work as a SQL statement. Of course... ? PS : I do not have direct control over the mysql engine

Comment: If you don't controll the server or can get someone to load this for you I think you have to rethink. Do date conversion in your application and store all dates in UTC. Never call now() but call utc_timestamp() instead.